How to Prevent Auto-Labeling from Reapplying Incorrect Labels to Specific Files?
I have created an auto-labeling policy that works well overall.
However, for a few files, the labels applied are incorrect. When I manually remove the label, it gets reapplied automatically.
Is there a way to remove the auto-label from specific files and prevent them from being re-labeled?

Could you share some details please? Why was the label incorrectly applied in the first place? Does the policy need adjusting perhaps?

Incorrect in the sense, there was some contract number into the document and Microsoft considered that as a SSN and it applied a wrong label. I removed the label manually but next day, I saw the same label was again reapplied.

You can apply a manual label to said document. I think auto label does not override manual label.
Also, you can test the file against sensitive information type for SSN. It will show you which confidence level the file is satisfying. Accordingly, you can fine-tune your auto label policy to ignore this false positive case
